# Python: Why my function returns None and then executes

Tags: python, return, nonetype

So, I have a function which basically does this:

```
import os
import json
import requests
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def function(data):
    statuslist = []
    for i in range(len(data[0])):
        result = performOperation(data[0][i])
        if result in satisfying_results:
            print("its okay")
            statuslist.append("Pass")
        else:
            print("absolutely not okay")
            statuslist.append("Fail" + result)
    return statuslist
```

Then, I invoke the function like this (I've added error handling to check what will happen after stumbling upon the reason for me asking this question), and was actually amazed by the results, as the function returns None, and then executes:

```
statuslist = function(data)
print(statuslist)
try:
    for i in range(len(statuslist)):
        anotherFunction(i)
        print("Confirmation that it is working")
except TypeError:
    print("This is utterly nonsense I think")
```

The output of the program is then as follows:

```
None
This is utterly nonsense I think
its okay
its okay
its okay
absolutely not okay
its okay
```

There is only single return statement at the end of the function, the function is not recursive, its pretty straightforward and top-down(but parses a lot of data in the meantime).

From the output log, it appears that the function first returns None, and then is properly executed. I am puzzled, and I were unable to find any similar problems over the internet (maybe I phrase the question incorrectly).
Even if there were some inconsistency in the code, I'd still expect it to return [] instead.

After changing the initial list to statuslist = ["WTF"], the return is [].
To rule out the fact that I have modified the list in some other functions performed in the function(data), I have changed the name of the initial list several times - the results are consistently beyond my comprehension

I will be very grateful on tips in debugging the issue. Why does the function return the value first, and is executed after?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough info to reproduce this. Do you mean `data[0]` in the for loop in the first function? What if you comment out lots of the code, then add it back in to see what happens?

Comment: Have you checked so that the modules you Import does not have code that gets run as they get Imported.
os, json and request I recognize so they are OK but the third party module you import might have code that is run on import, that would be my first check.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem without `data`, `performOperation()`, `satisfying_results` and `anotherFunction`.

Comment: Not reproducible. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well, there are lot of more functions which are nested in there, but all they do is to read data from excel, feed the data to definition of the calls used with requests module, and then send those calls to the server.

I will check commenting out parts of code to see if I could isolate the culprit. I tried to minimise the function to the root of it, as the full code, together with all the API call definitions, takes circa 300 lines.

Answer (score 0):

While being unable to write the code which would at the same time present what happened in my code in full spectrum, be readable, and wouldn't interfere with no security policies of the company, I have re-wrote it in a simpler form (the original code has been written while I had 3 months of programming experience), and the issue does not reproduce anymore. I guess there had be some level of nesting of functions that I have misinterpreted, and this re-written code, doing pretty much the same, correctly returns me the expected list.

Thank you everyone for your time and suggestions.

So, the answer appears to be: You do not understand your own code, make it simpler.